# MATLAB strange behaviour with mod() when using vpa()

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

If we have the following code:

```
base = vpa(1); 
height = vpa(2.2);
mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height))
```

This produces output of 6.4. I would expect the result to be 0 and the numeric solution does give 0. But I need to use symbolic values with `vpa()`.

I did some experimentation to find out why and found:

```
simplify(2*base + height + height < 6.4)
simplify(2 * (base + height) == 6.4)
```

both give `TRUE`. So the same (numeric) expression is smaller and equal to 6.4.

What should I do to fix this and get the answer of 0? What is causing this problem?

Comment: this is indeed an unexpected behavior. The analytically identical expressions are not the same in the Symbolic Math Toolbox. I would guess, it has something to do with roundings but I have no clue how the symbolic calculation work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `vpa` offers arbitrarily large precision, but **is not exact**. First off, note that [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) with a second input uses [`digits`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) precision digits, which is `32` by default. When you do

```
height = vpa(2.2)
```

this is the same as

```
height = vpa(2.2, 32)
```

assuming that `digits` is `32`. So `height` will have `32` digits of precision, but will not be exact. To see this, evaluate the defined `height` with more precision:

```
>> vpa(height, 32)
ans =
2.2
>> vpa(height, 40)
ans =
2.2
>> vpa(height, 50)
ans =
2.2000000000000000000000000000000000000001469367939
```

This inaccuracy introduces a numerical difference between `2*base + height + height` and `2 * (base + height)`, neither of which actually equals `6.4`:

```
>> base = vpa(1); 
>> height = vpa(2.2);
>> vpa(2*base + height + height, 50)
ans =
6.3999999999999999999999999999999999999988245056492
>> vpa(2 * (base + height), 50)
ans =
6.4000000000000000000000000000000000000002938735877
```

As a result, even if `mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height))` *seems* to be `0`

```
>> mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height))
ans =
6.4

but it's _not_:

>> vpa(mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height)), 50)
ans =
6.3999999999999999999999999999999999999988245056492
```

Note that the deviation from `6.4` in this latter result doesn't equal the sum of the two small deviations above; rather, it equals the first. Numerical inaccuracy is not guaranteed to be additive.

In short, **`vpa` diminishes, but doesn't completely avoid, numerical precision errors**.

---

What if we increase the number of digits used for `vpa`? Will that give more precision and maybe solve the issue?

```
>> base = vpa(1, 1000); 
>> height = vpa(2.2, 1000);
```

Strangely, inspite of having used more digits, we get the same inaccuracy as before:

```
>> vpa(2*base + height + height, 50)
ans =
6.3999999999999999999999999999999999999988245056492
>> vpa(2 * (base + height), 50)
ans =
6.4000000000000000000000000000000000000002938735877
>> vpa(mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height)), 50)
ans =
6.3999999999999999999999999999999999999988245056492
```

---

So, the only way to avoid precision errors is to replace `vpa` by **symbolic variables**, which are **exact**:

```
>> base = sym(1)
base =
1
>> height = sym(2.2)
height =
11/5
```

A digression on how to define symbolic variables is in order. Note that `sym(2.2)` has the potential problem that it *first* defines `2.2` as a `double` floating-point number, with its inherent inaccuracy, and *then* that is converted to `sym`. In this case that's not a problem, because the floating-point numerical representation of `2.2` happens to be exact. Indeed, we can check that Matlab displays `height = sym(2.2)`, which is exact. Furthermore, even if the `double` representation is not exact, Matlab tries to *guess* your intent, and often suceeds:

```
>> sym(3.141592653589793)
ans =
pi
```

(Matlab assumes we meant the number pi)... but not always:

```
>> sym(sqrt(777))
ans =
777^(1/2)
>> sym(sqrt(777777))
ans =
7757421003204227/8796093022208
```

(`sqrt(777)` gives the `double` result `27.874719729532707`, which is recognized by `sym` as an approximation of the square root of `777`. On the other hand, `sqrt(777777)` gives `8.819166627295348e+02`, which is not recognized by `sym` as an approximation of the square root of `777777`).

```
>> sym(7777)
ans =
7777
>> sym(7777777777777777777)
ans =
7777777777777777664
```

(`7777` is represented exactly as a `double`,  but `7777777777777777777` is not, because it exceeds `2^53`.)

So, to be sure, the **safe** way to define symbolic variables is to only use **small integers**, other **symbolic variables**, or **exact string representations**:

```
>> height = sym('22/10')
height =
11/5
```

Now, with `base` and `height` correctly defined as symbolic variables, we get the expected result:

```
>> mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height))
ans =
0
>> vpa(mod(2*base + height + height, 2 * (base + height)), 1000)
ans =
0.0
```

Comment: Interesting! I guess you could do `height = vpa(22, 1000) / vpa(10, 1000)`? Both should be represented exactly?

Comment: @CrisLuengo That has the same issue: the result is `2.2000000000000000000000000000000000000001469...`. Somehow `2.2` with `vpa` is inexact, even if it's exact as `double`

Answer (score 0):

```
mod(2*base + height + height, base+base+height+height)
```

This line of code produces 0. Still unsure exactly what is causing the problem behind the scenes. There seems to be a distinct difference between the product and sum as the following line of code is `FALSE`

```
mod(base+base+height+height, 2*(base+height))
```